# SSHFS/SFTP : Vim hangs when trying to edit file over sshfs and can't upload file over MTU size over sftp

Tags: ssh, vim, scp, sftp, sshfs

My university provides an ssh access to the students university accounts, and I just set up an sshfs to access some folders on my remote account.

I am running pop_os on my local machine and using systemd automount with following options : `noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,workaround=rename,IdentityFile=/home/me/.ssh/identityfile,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,ServerAliveInterval=15`

#### The issue

Automount works fine, I can browse my remote folder, but I have some trouble with replacing files and recursively copying folders to the remote.

But every time I try to edit a file on the remote fs with vim, the editor hangs for 60 seconds (very precisely, which I guess has something to do with the connection timeout parameters) before opening the file. When the file finally opens I get and error stating `E297: Write error in swap file` and on close `E72: Close error on swap file` from vim.

But sometimes (particularly after I have reloaded the dameon and restarted the automount service after updating options in /etc/fstab, the file opens instantly with no errors.

#### What I have tried

I ran strace when opening a file on the sshfs, here is a sample of the log where the issue seems to be happening :

```
     0.000032 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../myremotefile.c", O_RDONLY) = 3
     0.041890 readlink(".../myremotefile.c", 0x7ffd99b19540, 4095) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
     0.000302 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../.myremotefile.c.swp", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.029883 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../.myremotefile.c.swp", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
     0.103207 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../.myremotefile.c.swx", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.074409 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../.myremotefile.c.swx", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5
     0.116541 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000419 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.000318 close(5)                  = 0
     0.000268 unlink(".../.myremotefile.c.swx") = 0
     0.075053 close(4)                  = 0
     0.000448 unlink(".../.myremotefile.c.swp") = 0
     0.061916 stat(".../.myremotefile.c.swp", 0x7ffd99b1a4d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.077126 lstat(".../.myremotefile.c.swp", 0x7ffd99b1a660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.041249 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY) = 4
     0.000218 fchdir(4)                 = 0
     0.000197 chdir(".../myremotefolder") = 0
     0.000086 getcwd("/home/myhomefolder/.../myremotefolder", 4096) = 34
     0.000029 fchdir(4)                 = 0
     0.000025 close(4)                  = 0
     0.000027 lstat(".../.myremotefile.c.swp", 0x7ffd99b1a9e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.043704 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".../.myremotefile.c.swp", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW, 0600) = 4
     0.127965 fcntl(4, F_GETFD)         = 0
     0.000331 fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
     0.000347 openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY) = 5
     0.000221 fchdir(5)                 = 0
     0.000145 chdir(".../myremotefolder") = 0
     0.046751 getcwd("/home/myhomefolder/.../myremotefolder", 4096) = 34
     0.000375 fchdir(5)                 = 0
     0.000351 close(5)                  = 0
     0.000262 lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)     = 0
     0.000082 write(4, "b0VIM 8.1\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\217\266\235]>\0\0\0\335\16\0\0balo"..., 4096) = 4096
     0.000645 select(1, [0], [], [0], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
     0.000176 chmod("..../.myremotefile.c.swp", 0644) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
    60.064610 close(3)                  = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
```

You can see there that the process hangs for 60 seconds on close.

The issue seems to be happening when vim tries to create the .swp file, but I can't figure out why, because I have no trouble manually creating or deleting files or folders on the remote fs.

I don't understand sshfs and fuse enough to fix this on my own.

I can provide the strace logs for gcc and mv too. Ask me if you want precisions.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Edit :** I set the `directory` option in vimrc so that vim creates its swap file in my local .vim folder, which has solved the swap file errors I had.

But I still got some I/O errors while doing other operations, so I believe what was happening with vim is just the symptom of a more complex issue that I will try to investigate.

As stated by @roaima the issue seems to be caused by the connection unexpectedly closing, which happened when vim tried to create the swap file in the remote fs.

I recently noticed that I can't copy some files no matter what, I can't say for sure now but I think it may be files larger than a certain size, I need to do some tests.

**Edit2 :** After doing some tests today I noticed that when I try to upload a file exceeding the MTU size (1500) over ssh (I tried uploading a file over sshfs, scp and in a sftp session), when doing so with ssh `ServerAliveInterval` option set, connection drops after 60 seconds.

Comment: You say that you can "copy files from remote to local with no issues" but that "mv hangs for 60 seconds". Was it a `mv` from or to the remote? From the strace log, I see an error on the `chmod` call; are you sure of your permission options: uid, gid, etc

Comment: Does sftp to the server work? Can you upload and download files with `sftp`? Also, have you tried lowering the MTU to, e.g., 1300? If it's actually MTU-related, that will probably work...

Comment: The the mv was from the local to the remote, I think my problem might be due to a bad firewall configuration. I can pull files without troubles, but as soon as I want to upload a file over 1500 bytes (size of the mtu) the sftp hangs, and the ssh connection drops.

Comment: I have tried lowering a bit the MTU, I did not go as low as 1300 though, but it did not seem to have any effect. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so lowering the MTU size seems to have resolved all my I/O issues over SSHFS. As pointed by @roaima the issues were probably caused by the firewall of the university server blocking ICMP packets too eagerly.

Thanks to @roaima for guiding me toward the solution to that issue.
And thanks to @derobert for suggesting to lower the MTU.

Answer (score 1):

The `sshfs` FUSE filesystem is implemented by presenting a filesystem on top of `sftp`, the file transfer protocol. As a result, any file access such as editing with `vi[m]` requires the `sshfs` subsystem first to copy the file to a cache on the local filesystem. If the file is particularly large, or the network between your client and the server is particularly slow, it will take a measurable amount of time to transfer the file before it's accessible locally.

It's (very) broadly equivalent to the following (except it uses `sftp` instead of `scp`)

```
# Copy the remote file to a temporary local cache
scp -p remote:/path/to/file /tmp/file.tmp
checksum=$(cksum /tmp/file.tmp)

# Action on remote file is implemented by performing the action locally
vi /tmp/file.tmp

# Simplified; we would also need to handle local rm/mv -> remote rm/mv, etc.
[[ "$(cksum /tmp/file.tmp)" != "$checksum" ]] && scp -p /tmp/file.tmp remote:/path/to/file
```

As a consequence, you'll find that trying to run `gcc` locally will be measurably slower than just logging in to the remote server and running it there. To be honest I'm not overly surprised that "*gcc crashes when trying to compile files on the remote fs*". It shouldn't, of course, but then think about what's actually going on in the background...

Comment: Hi @roaima the file I edit are not particularly large (for example I still get the issue for a 10 lines long bash script) and the connection is pretty decent. Although I understand why gcc can fail using this set up, editing a small file over vim shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi again @roaima, creating the vim swap file locally (using the `set direcory dir` option in vimrc) instead of creating them in the folder containing the file edited completely fixed the vim delay for me, which narrows down my issue to why creating a vim swap file on the remote hangs sshfs for 60 seconds.

Comment: @Balocre agreed. I've just noticed the "Transport endpoint is not connected" message. That suggests your network connection was interrupted, breaking the `ssh` connection. Possible?

Comment: @Roiama yes it is I believe what is in fact happening, now I I have to determine why, my guess is that it is either a permission problem, which would somehow cause the connection to crash, but that would be strange because as stated I can create and delete file how I please on the remote (so why would vim not be able to), or a server configuarion/security issue, but I don't understand ssh enough yet to determine that, maybe I should try to contact the IT department.

Comment: I will keep you informed, because I am doing some tests right now, but it seems I can't create file over a certain size (which is not very big, I just tried to move a jpeg to the remote and go a `cp: failed to close /../myfileonremote.jpeg :  Input/output error`) which corrupted the file, and might be linked to the vim issue

Comment: The input/output error is a direct consequence of the "Transport endpoint is not connected" message. You need to try an investigate why your ssh connection is being closed underneath you.

Comment: I have found something rather strange, sftp hangs indefinitely when I try to upload a file exceeding the mtu (set at 1500) to the remote server, stalling all operations involving sshfs. I have tried it over sshfs, in a sftp session, and over scp. And if I set `ServerAliveInterval=15` option (like I did for sshfs) connection drops after 60 seconds (4*15?). I think I might be onto something, any idea what I should do next?

Comment: Ah. That's typically an over-zealous firewall that incorrectly blocks the ICMP messages that negotiate MTU. If the remote device responds to ping it's possible to test this out. By comparing results with known-working sites you can confirm whether it's your end at fault or theirs. Then you need to contact the sysadmins...

Comment: Ok, seems you are right, this is definitively an issue with my university server. I just rented a server and set up a sshfs to it, I had no issue with file transfer so far. I'll run some more test and write a mail to the IT tomorrow.
Now I still have to determine if that's what was causing my vim issues (even though I strongly suspect that yes)

Comment: Another hint toward the university blocking ICMP packet is that I can't ping it